# How to change cursor shape with NCurses in C?

Tags: c, ncurses

I was wondering if there was a function that allowed the cursor to change from its default rectangle to a character?

Comment: Have you tried sending commands to shell (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425103/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-color-in-ncurses-forms) to set the cursor character to one of these (http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/VGA-softcursor.txt?id=HEAD)?

Comment: No, I thought nurses had a function within it to do what I want. I am going to try this tonight

Comment: Still no answer to this question :(