# How to use a nested array as a value in a function?

Tags: c

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to define an array of arrays and access the values of the top level array in a function.

**What I've Tried**

For example:

```
// the array
char* myRGBColorArray[5][3] = { 
    {"0x00,","0x01,","0x02,"},  // i want to use this in a function
    {"0x03,","0x04,","0x05,"}, 
    {"0x06,","0x07,","0x08,"},
    {"0x09,","0x10,","0x11,"},
    {"0x12,","0x13,","0x14,"}
    };

// the function's format
// cursor_set_color_rgb(0xff, 0xff, 0xff);

// ideally i would like to use the indexed values, like this:
cursor_set_color_rgb(myRGBColorArray[0]);
cursor_set_color_rgb(myRGBColorArray[1]);  // etc
```

Very new to C, hence still trying to get my head around nested arrays, accessing indexed values, and defining types.

**Question/s**

- Is the `type` of `myRGBColorArray` defined above correct?
- How do I correctly access the indexed values of the array?

For reference, the function I am playing around with is from the second example here - it changes the color of the cursor:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18434383

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void cursor_set_color_rgb(unsigned char red,
                          unsigned char green,
                          unsigned char blue) {
    printf("\e]12;#%.2x%.2x%.2x\a", red, green, blue);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    cursor_set_color_rgb(0xff, 0xff, 0xff); sleep(1);
    cursor_set_color_rgb(0xff, 0xff, 0x00); sleep(1);
    cursor_set_color_rgb(0xff, 0x00, 0xff); sleep(1);
    cursor_set_color_rgb(0x00, 0xff, 0xff); sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the type of myRGBColorArray defined above correct?

Sort-of. You should really use `const char*` instead of `char*` when referring to string literals.

However, from your bottom example it seems you want an array of `unsigned char`'s instead:

```
unsigned char colors[5][3] = { 
    {0x00, 0x01, 0x02},
    {0x03, 0x04, 0x05}, 
    {0x06, 0x07, 0x08},
    {0x09, 0x10, 0x11},
    {0x12, 0x13, 0x14}
};
```

> How do I correctly access the indexed values of the array?

You can write the color function as such:

```
void cursor_set_color_rgb(unsigned char color[3]) {
    printf("\e]12;#%.2x%.2x%.2x\a", color[0], color[1], color[2]);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

And set the color to the fourth color in your array like this (remember that indexing starts at 0):

```
cursor_set_color_rgb(colors[3]);
```

Alternatively you can use the original function and use it like such:

```
cursor_set_color_rgb(colors[3][0], colors[3][1], colors[3][2]);
```