# Forcing ncurses to change the cursor color now

Tags: terminal, ncurses, xterm, terminal-emulator

I have a terminal program using ncurses that periodically changes the foreground and background colors.  Unfortunately, the cursor color won't change until the terminal scrolls.  What is ncurses doing during a scroll that causes xterm and other ANSI-compliant terminal emulators to change the cursor color?

I have this in my .Xresources:

```
xterm*cursorColor:      *XtDefaultForeground
```

I found this: [How do I change the cursor color in ncurses forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425103/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-color-in-ncurses-forms) showing me the escape sequence to change the cursor color, but it doesn't take into account the fact that the cursor is actually brighter because it's in bold.  I can multiply the values I get from `color_content()` with 1.48, but this strikes me as inviting trouble later on.
For some reason I can't figure out, just dividing the bold color by the non-bold color (values obtained with a color picker) didn't work.  The resulting color was brighter, but didn't match the target value, so I found 1.48 by trial and error.

If I'm stuck with using escape sequences, that's okay, but I'd like to know of a cleaner way to properly bold a color.

Answer (score 0):

ncurses doesn't know anything about cursor-color: there's no commonality across terminals to assume that one can set (or control) the cursor color.

The [xterm sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-1-2.1017) indicated may/may not be supported by other terminals.  It happens to modify the value which would be initialized by the [cursorColor](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:cursorColor) resource:

> Specifies the color to use for the text cursor.  The default is
>   *`"XtDefaultForeground"`*.  By default, **`xterm`** attempts to keep this
>   color from being the same as the background color, since it
>   draws the cursor by filling the background of a text cell.  The
>   same restriction applies to control sequences which may change
>   this color.
>
> Setting this resource overrides most of **`xterm`**'s adjustments to
>   cursor color.  It will still use reverse-video to disallow some
>   cases, such as a black cursor on a black background.

That is, by default, xterm attempts to keep the cursor visible by adjusting its color based on the ***cell*** where the cursor currently is.  As you move the cursor around in a text field, those colors may be different, causing xterm to change the cursor color.

Now... there are some special cases (see [**`ShowCursor`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/94c7ce6cab2371ba6eec668ab7c9c3dd28e076b5/charproc.c#L11387) and [**`HideCursor`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/94c7ce6cab2371ba6eec668ab7c9c3dd28e076b5/charproc.c#L11774) in the xterm source), but basically it tries to use the current cell's foreground/background colors (reversed).  In ncurses, you can get the cell's current colors by using one of the [**`inch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html) or [**`in_wch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_in_wch.3x.html) variations.  The returned data includes a *color pair*, and you can extract the *color values* for foreground/background from that using [pair_content](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-pair_content).  Reversing those to make a new color pair would be close (but you're already aware that **bold** can interact with the rendered color).

Comment: I understand this.  The ncurses angle I was after was figuring out just what happens when text is scrolled because that's when the cursor's color changes.  Since it's clear that's not possible, I want to figure out how to reliably and cleanly convert an ncurses color to what it would be if it was bolded.